# PHP - Error while binding variable to the Prepared Statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

Trying to bind a Variable **$user_id** to the prepared statement, the array is sent as an jsonarray to a java file.
The below code works perfectly fine but it is without the binded parameter, where the value of **qual_id** is static.

```
if ($user_id->num_rows >= 1) {
        $mysql_qry = "select * from user_qualification where qual_id='1'";
        //$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        //$result = mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $mysql_qry);
        //mysqli_stmt_bind_param($result, "i", $user_id);

       $result = mysqli_query($conn,$mysql_qry);
        //mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

        $data_item = array();
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            array_push($data_item, 
            array('u_school'=>$row['school'],
            'u_hschool'=>$row['hschool'],
            'u_undergrad'=>$row['ugrad'],
            'u_grad'=>$row['grad'],
            'u_phd'=>$row['phd'],
            )
            );
        }
```

Below code contains error which is with the binded parameter:

```
if ($user_id->num_rows >= 1) {
    $mysql_qry = "select * from user_qualification where qual_id='?'";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    $result = mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $mysql_qry);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($result, "s", $user_id);

    //$result = mysqli_query($conn,$mysql_qry);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    $data_item = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        array_push($data_item, 
        array('u_school'=>$row['school'],
        'u_hschool'=>$row['hschool'],
        'u_undergrad'=>$row['ugrad'],
        'u_grad'=>$row['grad'],
        'u_phd'=>$row['phd'],
        )
        );
    }
```

Also the column **qual_id** is bigint.

**Edit 1:**
removed the quotations of placeholder.
$mysql_qry = "select * from user_qualification where qual_id=?";

**Edit 2 :**
changed from "s" to "i".
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($result, "i", $user_id);

**Edit 3 :**
**var_dump** of variable $user_id after the if statement
object(mysqli_result)#3 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(1) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(1) ["type"]=> int(0) } []

**Edit 4 :**
php file

```
<?php
require "conn.php";
$user_name ="omx123"; //$_POST["user_name"];
if ($mysql_qry = $conn->prepare("Select id from UserLoginDetails where username=?")) {
    $mysql_qry->bind_param("s", $user_name);
    $mysql_qry->execute();
    $user_id = $mysql_qry->get_result();

    if ($user_id->num_rows >= 1) {
        var_dump($user_id);
        $mysql_qry = "select * from user_qualification where qual_id=?";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        $result = mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $mysql_qry);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($result, "i", $user_id);

        //$result = mysqli_query($conn,$mysql_qry);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

        $data_item = array();
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            array_push($data_item, 
            array('u_school'=>$row['school'],
            'u_hschool'=>$row['hschool'],
            'u_undergrad'=>$row['ugrad'],
            'u_grad'=>$row['grad'],
            'u_phd'=>$row['phd'],
            )
            );
        }
        echo json_encode($data_item);
    }
} 
$conn->close();
?>
```

**Edit 5:**
Thank you for your help user : dWinder
var_dump on $user_id :
int(1) []
But the array is still empty.

**Edit 6:**
Works perfectly fine now :D

```
$mysql_qry = "select * from user_qualification where qual_id=?";
         $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
         mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $mysql_qry);
         mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $user_id_int);
         mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
         $result=mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
```

Comment: `'?'` You shouldn't be using quotes.

Comment: I guess it is because you are binding int param as string, try to change it to     mysqli_stmt_bind_param($result, "i", $user_id);

Comment: Remove the quotes from the placeholder

Comment: To explain, anything inside of quotes would be considered a string. So by quoting the question mark, it becomes a string containing a question mark and not a placeholder.

Comment: Removed the quotations of placeholder and changed the "s" to "i" in mysqli_stmt_bind_param but it still doesn't work.

Comment: "Doesn't work" doesn't give us anything to go by. Do some debugging and tell us exactly where your code is failing and how.

Comment: You're apparently also trying to pass an object `$user_id` as a string. That won't work.

Comment: It is look like `$user_id` is not int or string as you doing `if ($user_id->num_rows >= 1)`  - can you please share `var_dump` on `$user_id`?

Comment: Yes sure! I'll provide a var_dump.

Comment: No-one has asked the obvious question...what is the actual error you are seeing? Can you paste it above?

Comment: And ... `var_dump of variable $user_id`...that dump looks like like it's a mysqli_result object - i.e. the result object generated by an earlier query. It's not an integer or string or any other simple type. Where is `$user_id` coming from? We can't see that in your code. Did you perhaps mean to get the result of an earlier query, and get the data from it...but in fact you just passed the raw result object instead of actually reading the data? Without seeing where the variable comes from, it's hard to be sure, but that's what it looks like....

Comment: ...Surely you can see yourself from the dump output that it's not going to be a valid thing to pass to your query and be treated as an integer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you share the dump of the `$user_id` it seem it is mysql result. In order to extract you ID from there you should use `mysqli_fetch_assoc`.

```
if ($user_id->num_rows >= 1) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($user_id)
    $user_id_int = $row["id"]; // or what ever you used to call it

    // now you can call the bind...
    $mysql_qry = "select * from user_qualification where qual_id=?";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    $result = mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $mysql_qry);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($result, "i", $user_id_int);
```

**I assume you use query as: "SELECT id From ..." as when you get the `$user_id`**

Comment: Thank you! 
this solved it, and I'm getting the value in var_dump as the $user_id value but the array is shown empty

Comment: @Ompanchal Glad to help! If this post helped you consider marking it as accepted (the grey "v" at the left of the post) so other may use it

Comment: typo: `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($result, "i", $user_id);`  should be `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($result, "i", $user_id_int);` to make use of the new value. otherwise, good answer :-)